# How NAT / PortForwarding / TCP/IP works?

Tags: nat, tcp

I recently read an article entitled [how NAT works](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/nat.htm). Some things still remain unclear to me. I would be thankful if someone could explain.

Below is the part of the article regarding DynamicNAT that is most confusing:

> A computer on the stub domain attempts to connect to a computer
>   outside the network, such as a Web server.
>
> The router receives the packet from the computer on the stub domain.
>   The router saves the computer's non-routable IP address to an address
>   translation table. The router replaces the sending computer's
>   non-routable IP address with the first available IP address out of the
>   range of unique IP addresses. The translation table now has a mapping
>   of the computer's non-routable IP address matched with the one of the
>   unique IP addresses.
>
> When a packet comes back from the destination computer, the router
>   checks the destination address on the packet. It then looks in the
>   address translation table to see which computer on the stub domain the
>   packet belongs to.

1) How does NAT know that the packet "comes back" to destination computer?

2) What if other computers in the LAN are connected to the same server? How does the NAT know which packet should "come back" where?

3) Does the packet header modification allow to perform an Internet attack, in which the "source IP" is replaced with the victim's IP, and the answering server will flood victim with unwanted packets?

I guess multiple attackers would need to be involved...

4) Is StaticNAT equivalent to the PortForwarding of all ports?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a general misconception between [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) (Network address translation) and PAT (Port Address Translation), which is what we mostly use in our home routers.

**NAT**
Let's assume we have a network with the following topology:

*Private_Network* <-------> *Router* <-------> *The_Internet*

The interface of the *Router* that is connected to the *Private_Network* has [a private IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network), i.e. one that is not unique in *The_Internet*. On the other hand, in the case of **NAT**, *Router* has **multiple** interfaces connected to *The_Internet*. Each interface has a unique IP address in *The_Internet*. Now let's assume that *Host_A* and *Host_B* are in the *Private_Network* and they both want to access *Website_X* in *The_Internet* at the same time. The IPs and the ports of *Host_A*'s packet will be:

Source IP: *Host_A*'s private IP
Source Port: A port on *Host_A*
Destination IP: *Website_X*'s public/unique IP
Destination Port: A port where *Website_X*'s server is listening to

and in the same way for a packet coming from *Host_B*.
If the Source IP is left unchanged, then *Website_X* will reply to an IP address that is private, i.e. not unique, and therefore the packet will never be able to find it's way back. In order to solve that problem, the *Router* checks whether one of his unique IP addresses connected to *The_Internet* is not used. If that is the case, it does the following mapping:

*Host_A*'s private IP ======= *Router's_unique_IP_K*

and now the packet that started from *Host_A* going to *Website_X* and is now leaving the interface of the *Router* connected to *The_Internet* will have the form:

Source IP: *Router's_unique_IP_K*
Source Port: A port on *Host_A*
Destination IP: *Website_X*'s public/unique IP
Destination Port: A port where *Website_X*'s server is listening to

Thus you can understand that there is an one-to-one association from private IPs to public IPs. Therefore when a packet arrives from *Website_X* to the *Router*, this association is checked and the destination IP address is changed back to the private one and delivered successfully to the right host. 
As you can see, this method is quite simple, but it has one big disadvantage: each private host has to have a unique IP address reserved, which is expensive, thus we select to have fewer unique IP addresses than hosts in the private network. Therefore if all the private hosts attempt to access *The_Internet* at the same time, only a subset of them, equal to the number of the available public IP addresses that the *Router* has, will have access and the rest will be denied.
In order to counter that we created **PAT**.

**PAT**
**PAT** is what the vast majority of our home routers is using. The basic limitation is that the *Router* has a single unique IP address with which it connects to *The_Internet*, but we still want to allow multiple hosts from the private network to access *The_Internet* at the same time. 
The way we do that is "similar" to the way **NAT** does it with a key difference: instead of the *Router* holding a pool of IP address, it holds a pool of port numbers. More precisely, a packet arriving at the *Router* from *Host_A* in the *Private_Network* destined to *Website_X* in *The_Internet* will have the following format:

Source IP: *Host_A*'s private IP
Source Port: A port on *Host_A*
Destination IP: *Website_X*'s public/unique IP
Destination Port: A port where *Website_X*'s server is listening to

Now the *Router* will do two tasks:

1. It will change the Source IP to the *Router*'s unique public IP **AND**
2. It will change the Source Port to a port from a pool that the *Router* is maintaining and is not already used, e.g. *Port_Z*

and now the packet that started from *Host_A* going to *Website_X* and is now leaving the interface of the *Router* connected to *The_Internet* will have the form:

Source IP: *Router's_unique_IP_K*
Source Port: *Port_Z*
Destination IP: *Website_X*'s public/unique IP
Destination Port: A port where *Website_X*'s server is listening to

and the *Router* will keep the following mapping:

*Host_A*'s private IP **AND** a port on *Host_A* ======= *Port_Z*

Why does this work?
 
Now when a packet comes back, the *Router* simply checks the destination port number and changes the destination IP address and the destination port number according to the pre-mentioned mapping and the packet gets delivered successfully.

What if I run multiple applications on the same Host?
Different applications will have different ports, by definition, thus they will mapped to a different port from the *Router*.

What if multiple Hosts attempt to access *The_Internet* at the same time and they all use the same application?
Different Hosts will have different private IP addresses, by definition, thus they will mapped to a different port from the *Router*.

**PAT** is dangerously balancing in a grey space of cross-layer. Port numbers are part of the Transport Protocol while Routers are allowed to operate up to the Internet Protocol. So technically speaking is something that is not allowed by the protocols. Therefore there are, at least theoretically, potential dangers: the port pool is limited. Therefore if my private network consists of 1000 Hosts and each one is running port_pool/10 applications, the mapping table at the router will run out of available entries and access to applications will be denied.

This answer greatly exceeded my intended length, but I hope it was helpful.

Comment: A couple of notes, Firstly you are using the term "NAT" to reffer to what the RFCs call "Basic NAT" and "PAT" to reffer to what the RFCs call "NAPT". The RFCs generally use "NAT" as an umbrella term covering both "Basic NAT" and "NAPT". Secondly even "Basic NAT" has to modify the TCP/UDP header because the TCP/UDP header contains a checksum which covers the IP addresses.

Comment: @PeterGreen but is the gist of the answer accurate?

Answer (score 6):

The router knows where packets belong because `The router saves ... an address translation table.` It remembers what inside-outside address translations it has made. As such, one inside address equals one outside address, and the out-on-the-internet destination is irrelevant. This, of course, ignores the firewall present in practically every NAT router, which tracks full connections:

```
(inside) src:ip+port,dst:ip+port <-> (outside) src:ip+port,dst:ip+port
```

NAT can change any combination of ip and/or port.

#3 is any entirely different subject: *spoofing*

#4 "Static NAT", or "1-to-1", is an address only map. So, port (and even protocol: tcp, udp, gre, etc.) is irrelevant.

Comment: 2) What if other computers in the LAN are connected to the same server? How does the NAT know which packet should "come back" where?

Comment: 1 & 2 are the same answer: because it's tracking connections/translations. Two inside hosts will not be mapped to the same outside address; so any packet arriving at a mapped outside address, automatically has only one inside destination. If you only have one outside (public) address, then it's not "NAT", but PAT (port translation)